# Authentication flow - react native and navigating to and from <AuthStack> <RootStack

Tags: react-native, authentication, redux, react-navigation

I've been reading the React Navigation authentication docs and i can't seem to get my authentication working like the example describes - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/.

I have the following code in my authentication (with redux)

```
Class App extends Component{
render(){
 return (
      (this.props.userId == null ? <AuthStack /> : <RootStack />)
    )
  }
}
```

my Redux-Logger is sending me the following message, but as you can see from my console.log, the this.props.userId is coming back as undefined... why?

[image]

Here is my ACTION in the auth.js (action) file

```
export const getUserId = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then(userId => {
            console.log(userId)
            dispatch(setUserId(userId))
            // this.props.navigation.navigate(userId ? 'Main' : 'Login');
        })
    }
}
```

Here is my REDUCER in the auth.js (reducer) file

```
const initialState = {
    userId: ''
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USERID:
            return {
                ...state,
                userId: action.payload
            };
        case REMOVE_USERID:
            return {
                ...state,
                userId: null
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is the app.js right? do you have a connect wrapping this and having mapStateToProps and mapping userId ?

Comment: we need more code

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz - i've added more code (my reducer and auth)

Comment: did u mapStateToProps App Component ? if not that is the reason you get undefined

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the full scope of your redux implementation, majorly how you're getting the userId into the props of the component.

I'm guessing you're using "mapStateToProps".

Wrong!

```js
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        userId: state.userId
    })
```

Correct

```js
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        userId: state.auth.userId
    })
```